# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'array' has already been declared

Tags: javascript

```js
const array = ['Javascript', 'PHP', 'RUBY', 'ReactJS'];
function logger(...rest){
console.log(rest);
}
logger(...array);
```

I'm learning about rest parameters and spread in JavaScript ES6 but when I declare array in `let` or `const` form I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'array' has already been declared" but I don't declare it twice or change the data of array so can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Are you executing this in a REPL, such as the browser console or a Node.js terminal? Which execution context are you running this code in? Obviously, this code works just fine, when isolated.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I edited my code again, I use const and run in browser(about:blank)

Comment: I think the problem is that you are executing your code many times in the console. After the first time the variable is already declared so if you use the code again an error will happen. Try reloading the page and then putting the code on the console again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` variables can only be declared once. The browser keeps track of what variables were defined and gives you an error if you declare a `const` variable again even if has the same value. Variables declared with `let` have a similar restriction.

To fix this, reload the page with <kbd>F5</kbd>, and open the console with <kbd>F12</kbd>, and then try running the same code again. This time it should work. Reloading the page fixes the error because it clears the variables declared in the console, which makes the names of those variables available for reuse.

If reloading the page doesn't do anything, try typing the URL of the page you're testing the code on in the address bar of said page, and press enter. I noticed in a comment you're running your code on about:blank and at least in Firefox, refreshing about:blank does nothing.

Neither Chrome nor Edge give an error if you run the same code repeatedly in the console without refreshing in between but Firefox does.